# rsync with -X option doesn't work

Tags: macos, rsync

I'm concidering syncing files between 2 OSX machines(MBPs) with rsync.

After installed the newest rsync(3.1.3 I checked) on both MBPs by homebrew, I tried following command on the old MBP:

```
rsync -vahEPzXe ssh foo bar@newMBP.local:~/.
```

But it returned:

```
rsync: on remote machine: -vlogDtpXrze.iLsfxC: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/main.c(1337) [server=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.3]
```

Then I dropped -X option, it worked.

```
rsync -vahEPze ssh foo bar@newMBP.local:~/.
...
sent 1.29G bytes  received 197.52K bytes  12.62M bytes/sec
total size is 1.66G  speedup is 1.28
```

I use tags to manage files, and they are not preserved without -X option, so now I'm in trouble.

Can anyone help me fix that or suggest any other ways to sync tag information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That sounds like it's running the built-in rsync (v2.6.9), which does not support `-X` (it does support transferring extended attributes, but using a different and incompatible format). You can force it use v3 on the remote side with something like `--rsync-path=/usr/local/bin/rsync` (or whatever the correct filepath for v3 is on the remote computer).

Comment: I'm very sorry for the late reply. This answer completely fixed my problem. Thank you.